# Check if one line segments is entirely on the other line segment

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm as mentioned in the subject. It is as follows:

```
 int orientation(glm::i16vec2 &p1,
                 glm::i16vec2 &p2,
                 glm::i16vec2 &p3)
 {
   return (((p3.x - p1.x) * (p2.y - p1.y)) - ((p2.x - p1.x) * (p3.y - p1.y)));
 }


 bool onSegment(const glm::i16vec2 &pi,
                const glm::i16vec2 &pj,
                const glm::i16vec2 &pk)
 {
   if((std::min(pi.x,pj.x) <= pk.x && pk.x <= std::max(pi.x,pj.x)) &&
      (std::min(pi.y,pj.y) <= pk.y && pk.y <= std::max(pi.y,pj.y)))
    return true;
   else
    return false;
 }

 int main()
 {
   glm::i16vec2 hs(5,2);  // p1
   glm::i16vec2 he(5,3); // p2


   glm::i16vec2 cs(5,1);   // p3
   glm::i16vec2 ce(5,3); // p4

   int d1 = orientation(cs,ce,hs);
   int d2 = orientation(cs,ce,he);
   int d3 = orientation(hs,he,cs);
   int d4 = orientation(hs,he,ce);

   if((d1 == 0 && d2 == 0 && d3 == 0 && d4 == 0) &&
        (onSegment(cs,ce,hs) && onSegment(cs,ce,he)))
   {
    std::cout << "HPs is entirely inside CPs" << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

So far it working fine. Is there any leak within procedure when it may not work as intended in some situations ? Would like  to know about those scenarios ...

Thanks

Comment: explain your API. I would expect to see something like vertices A1,B1, A2,B2. Beside, what about the case they are not even aligned ? what kind of error threshold do you plan ?

Comment: If integers are 32 bits, the multiplies in orientation could overflow if p1's coordinates are large negatives and p2, p3's coordinates are large positives. Other than that, this looks correct - cross products are zero, h's vertexes are within the bounding box of c.

Comment: will it solve the issue if d1, d2 , d3 and d3 are stored as 64-bit integer type instead ?

Comment: "orientation" would have to compute with 64 bit integers too; the math there is currently promoted to integers, but they won't quite hold your worst case multiply result (if 32 bits). If you know your original data is limited (e.g. I think if you only had positive values - effectively positive 15 bit values, assuming 2's compliment integers), this may not be a problem. Start with a test that fails due to overflow, then work modify to fix. That is, prove my thinking isn't wrong before using the extra bits (or another strategy)... ;)